# How to test Async SQL Databases with Encode/Databases(Package) in FastAPI

Tags: python, database, unit-testing, pytest, fastapi

Question:

```
- How to run tests in isolation that don't create entries in database.
- Also, How we can use the isolated user that is created during the test for other endpoint testing
```

Some minimal code:

```
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
import databases
import sqlalchemy
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel, EmailStr

DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://user:password@postgresserver/db"
database = databases.Database(DATABASE_URL)

metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
users = sqlalchemy.Table(
    "users",
    metadata,
    sqlalchemy.Column("id", sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True),
    sqlalchemy.Column("first_name", sqlalchemy.String, nullable=True),
    sqlalchemy.Column("last_name", sqlalchemy.String, nullable=True),
    sqlalchemy.Column("email", sqlalchemy.String, index=True,
                      nullable=False, unique=True),
    sqlalchemy.Column("password", sqlalchemy.String,
                      index=True, nullable=False),
)

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    DATABASE_URL
)
metadata.create_all(engine)

class UserBase(BaseModel):
    first_name: str | None
    last_name: str | None
    email: EmailStr
 
class UserCreate(UserBase):
    password: str

app = FastAPI()


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    await database.connect()
    yield
    await database.disconnect()


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

class UserRepository:
    async def create(self, obj_in: UserCreate):
        query = users.insert().values(
            first_name=obj_in.first_name,
            last_name=obj_in.last_name,
            email=obj_in.email,
            password=obj_in.password,
        )
        await database.execute(query=query)
        return obj_in

    async def get_by_email(self, email: str):
        query = users.select().where(email == users.c.email)
        return await database.fetch_one(query=query)
    
user_repository = UserRepository()

@app.post("/", response_model=UserBase)
async def create_user(
    payload: UserCreate,
):
    if await user_repository.get_by_email(payload.email):
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=400,
            detail="The user with this username already exists in the database.",
        )
    return await user_repository.create(payload)

##### Testing 

import pytest
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

@pytest.fixture()
def client():
    with TestClient(app) as c:
        yield c


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
async def db():
    database = databases.Database(DATABASE_URL, force_rollback=True)
    await database.connect()
    yield database
    await database.disconnect()


async def test_create_user_endpoint(client: TestClient):
    user_data = UserCreate(
        first_name="John",
        last_name="Doe",
        email="JohnDoe@example.in",
        password="pass123",
    )
    response = client.post("/", json=user_data.dict())
    assert response.status_code == 200
    created_user = response.json()
    assert created_user["first_name"] == "John"
    assert created_user["last_name"] == "Doe"
```

The issue at involves unexpected behavior when running a FastAPI test multiple times using Pytest. The intention is to ensure test isolation by utilizing the force_rollback=True option in the test database fixture. However, despite using this option, the test fails on subsequent runs, indicating that the user already exists in the database.

Comment: Where are you using the database connection you're creating with `force_rollback=True`? Your application works with the `database` object defined in your application, and not the one you've defined inside your fixture. For your second question; creating users that you can use in your tests - that's what a fixture is for, so define a fixture named `created_user` or something similar, which creates the user (through the API) and hands the created user off to the test. A new user will then be created for each test.

Comment: Yeah, That's what I want to know how I can create `force_rollback=True` for testing because using the fixture is not working?

Comment: In FastAPI you'll generally use a dependency with  `Depends` for that, then use `app.dependency_overrides` to return an alternatively configured instance when you're testing. In this case you could have a dependency on a `get_user_service` which creates the user service with a given database connection, which can in turn be a dependency as well - you then override the `get_db` dependency to return a different instance when you're running your tests.

Comment: Even using `app.dependency_overrides` it is creating a user in the database it not getting rollback. look this is what I have done for the above code:

```@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
async def override_get_db():
    database = databases.Database(DATABASE_URL, force_rollback=True)
    await database.connect()
    yield database
    await database.disconnect()

app.dependency_overrides[database] = override_get_db

@pytest.fixture()
def client():
    with TestClient(app) as c:
        yield c```

After this `test_create_user_endpoint` is creating new user in datbase

Comment: You have to change your endpoints as well to actually use `Depends` - you can't just use `dependency_overrides` and expect a variable somewhere inside your modules to change. `dependency_overrides` works with FastAPIs `Depends` for dependency injection in a controller endpoint. The override-functions are not fixtures - that is a pytest thing, so you might want to define a fixture that configures the override in that case. Also having `session` means that it doesn't get rolled back for every test, so if that's what you're looking for you'll have to adjust the lifespan.